# Getting tax refund before departure from Singapore

Tags: airports, singapore, refunds, tax-refunds

Is it possible to get tax refund before departure, that is before having tickets to depart, during your stay.

The case is with Singapore.

Comment: Do you mean getting a tax refund at the point of purchase / purchasing tax free? Or going to somewhere in advance of your departure?

Answer (score 1):

**No**, it's not possible (legally).  [Tax refunds are only available](https://www.iras.gov.sg/IRASHome/GST/Consumers/Tourist-Refund-Scheme/) when *departing* Singapore via air or sea.

See [Is it possible to get a tax refund on goods in Singapore when leaving by land?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48317/is-it-possible-to-get-a-tax-refund-on-goods-in-singapore-when-leaving-by-land) for a full discussion of the law, a potential workaround, and the risks involved.